# How to execute string containing function name AND parameters?

Tags: javascript, eval

In javascript, I have a string like this:

```
"doSomething('param1','param2')"
```

And I want to execute it. I am aware that I could normally use

```
window['doSomething']('param1', 'param2');
```

But that only works if my function name is separate from the arguments. In my case they are already combined. I think I can use eval() but the consensus seems to be that it should be avoided. Is there another way?

**EDIT:**
To answer the request for more info: I am using this string like this:

```
<a id="YesButton" onclick="closeModalView_Yes("doSomething('param1','param2')")">
```

Where closeModalView_Yes will close the modal yes/no window and then execute the given function, although at times I may pass it doSomethingElse(param1) which only takes one parameter.

Comment: If you know what's in the string and won't be surprised ever, just use eval. I mean, you can't ever allow a user to assign the string's value.

Comment: How did you get that string, and why? Can't you make it an array `['doSomething', 'param1' 'param2']`?

Comment: Why don't you pass a callback to `closeModalView_Yes` instead? Something like `closeModalView_Yes(function () { doSomething('param1','param2'); })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval, just like:

```
eval( "console.log( 'hey', 'here I am' )" );
```

However [eval is pretty dangerous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21) and it's not recommended.

If you can (still we don't have much info about your case), render your JavaScript between `<script>` tags in your template, making it a "regular code", much easier to debug.

Also a good practice is to pass data (i.e. with JSON) rather than code. Try rethinking your logic or provide additional information.

Comment: With respect to "security", there is no difference between using `eval` or using a `script` element to execute the code though.

Comment: @FelixKling In terms of security - not much. In terms of debugging - hell yes! ;)

Comment: I agree. But since you mentioned both in the same paragraph it sounded like `script` was safer. Just wanted to clarify that :)

Comment: @FelixKling Agreed. Fixed the answer to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <a id="YesButton" onclick="closeModalView_Yes("doSomething('param1','param2')")">
> ```

You really shouldn't pass that as a string, but as a function:

```
closeModalView_Yes(function(){ doSomething('param1','param2'); });
```

together with

```
function closeModalView_Yes(callback) {
    // do whatever needs to be done to close the window
    // and after that
    callback();
}
```

Btw, with your current approach the HTML is not even valid, it would need to be

```
<a id="YesButton" onclick="closeModalView_Yes(&quot;doSomething('param1','param2')&quot;)">
<!--                                          ^^^^^^                              ^^^^^^ -->
```

You could've avoided that by registering the event [via javascript](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) instead of inline attributes.